# ASP.Net can read SQLite database but can't insert in win 7

Tags: asp.net, database, sqlite

I am using asp.net with sqlite database, I can read inserted records but can't insert records into sqlite database.

I faced with same problem in win vista and 7 with win app and I fixed by using Right Click->Run as Administrator.

Can I use asp.net to run as administrator.

I am using Windows 7.

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you keep your database? Not in program files, i hope?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your SQLite database file is in a folder that does not have write permissions for the account that your ASP.NET account is running under.